# $f$ is additive and continuous at a point $\implies$ $f(x) =ax$, for some $a \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.
> Suppose there exists at least an element $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Then prove that $f(x)=ax$, for some $x \in \mathbb R$.

Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the Cauchy equation $f(x) = ax$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$ and all $x \in \mathbb Q$.

Then proof that if $f$ is continuous at a point, it is continuous everywhere.

Then use the continuity to conclude that $f(x) = ax$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Note that there is always a rational number between two reals.